# "Relative" lifting property for covering spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X\xrightarrow{Q}Y$ be a covering space.
Let $A\subset B$ be a pair of spaces.

Suppose $B$ is path-connected and simply-connected.

Suppose $f : A \rightarrow X$ and $g : B \rightarrow Y$ are maps fitting into a commutative diagram below:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> X\\
@V{\text{incl.}}VV @V{Q}VV\\
B @>{g}>> Y
\end{CD}

Then does there exist a unique map $F : B\rightarrow X$ which, when placed in the above diagram, makes the resulting upper-left and lower-right triangles commute?

Is it possible to use the homotopy lifting property (unique lifting for $B$ path-connected) of covering spaces to prove the above?

Comment: You need to add the assumption that $A$ is path-connected.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, thank you! Would you be able to suggest a counter-example showing how the above fails if $A$ is not path-connected?

Comment: Let $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = [0,1]$ be the interval. Then if $X = Y \times \{0,1\}$ is a trivial two-sheeted cover and $y \in Y$, we can let $f(i) = (y,i) : A \to X$, and $g(b) = y$. This can't lift, since any map from $B \to X$ will be in one connected component, but we chose $f$ so that the two endpoints land in different components.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I see, thanks!

Comment: Similar examples exist when $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. I don't know if this is what you're looking for in an answer, but covering spaces are [fibrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration), so by abstract nonsense any "acyclic cofibration" will lift against it. Intuitively, this means we want $A$ to sit "nicely" as a subspace of $B$ (think of a sub-cell complex), and the inclusion should be a (weak) homotopy equivalence. This is probably overkill, though